# Dataflow setting Controller Service Account

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, dataflow, google-cloud-iam

I try to set up controller service account for Dataflow. In my dataflow options I have:

```
options.setGcpCredential(GoogleCredentials.fromStream(
                         new FileInputStream("key.json")).createScoped(someArrays)); 
options.setServiceAccount("xxx@yyy.iam.gserviceaccount.com");
```

But I'm getting:

```
WARNING: Request failed with code 403, performed 0 retries due to IOExceptions,         
         performed 0 retries due to unsuccessful status codes, HTTP framework says 
         request can be retried, (caller responsible for retrying): 
         https://dataflow.googleapis.com/v1b3/projects/MYPROJECT/locations/MYLOCATION/jobs
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to create a workflow 
         job: (CODE): Current user cannot act as 
         service account "xxx@yyy.iam.gserviceaccount.com. 
         Causes: (CODE): Current user cannot act as 
         service account "xxx@yyy.iam.gserviceaccount.com.
    at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.DataflowRunner.run(DataflowRunner.java:791)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.DataflowRunner.run(DataflowRunner.java:173)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline.run(Pipeline.java:311)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline.run(Pipeline.java:297)
```

...

```
Caused by: com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 403 Forbidden
{
  "code" : 403,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "message" : "(CODE): Current user cannot act as service account 
                 xxx@yyy.iam.gserviceaccount.com. Causes: (CODE): Current user
                 cannot act as service account xxx@yyy.iam.gserviceaccount.com.",
    "reason" : "forbidden"
  } ],
  "message" : "(CODE): Current user cannot act as service account 
               xxx@yyy.iam.gserviceaccount.com. Causes: (CODE): Current user 
               cannot act as service account xxx@yyy.iam.gserviceaccount.com.",
  "status" : "PERMISSION_DENIED"
}
```

Am I missing some Roles or permissions?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Maybe someone is going to find it helpful:

- For controller it was: Dataflow Worker and Storage Object Admin (that was found in [Google's documentation](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/concepts/access-control#example_role_assignment)).
- For executor it was: Service Account User.

Comment: For terraform I have used:   
```roles        = ["dataflow.admin", "dataflow.worker", "storage.admin", "iam.serviceAccountUser"]```

Comment: @Kush - thanks. a lot. This resolves my issue.

Comment: A note: based on the least principle of least privilege, you my want to restrict the roles to the respective resources (e.g. only apply to a bucket rather than project-level, also grant service account user on the specific SA level rather than on project level)

Comment: If you're using a service account just for deploying the Dataflow job, I don't think the `dataflow.worker` role is necessary?

Answer (score 6):

I've been hitting this error and thought it worth sharing my experiences (partly because I suspect I'll encounter this again in the future).

The terraform code to create my dataflow job is:

```
resource "google_dataflow_job" "wordcount" {
  # https://stackoverflow.com/a/59931467/201657
  name              = "wordcount"
  template_gcs_path = "gs://dataflow-templates/latest/Word_Count"
  temp_gcs_location = "gs://${local.name-prefix}-functions/temp"
  parameters = {
    inputFile = "gs://dataflow-samples/shakespeare/kinglear.txt"
    output = "gs://${local.name-prefix}-functions/wordcount/output"
  }
  service_account_email = "serviceAccount:${data.google_service_account.sa.email}"
}
```

The error message:

> Error: googleapi: Error 400: (c3c0d991927a8658): Current user cannot act as service account serviceAccount:dataflowdemo@redacted.iam.gserviceaccount.com., badRequest

was returned from running `terraform apply`. Checking out the logs provided a lot more info:

```sh
gcloud logging read 'timestamp >= "2020-12-31T13:39:58.733249492Z" AND timestamp <= "2020-12-31T13:45:58.733249492Z"' --format="csv(timestamp,severity,textPayload)" --order=asc
```

which returned various log records, including this:

> Permissions verification for controller service account failed. IAM role roles/dataflow.worker should be granted to controller service account dataflowdemo@redacted.iam.gserviceaccount.com.

so I granted that missing role grant

```sh
gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding $PROJECT \
  --member="serviceAccount:dataflowdemo@${PROJECT}.iam.gserviceaccount.com" \
  --role="roles/dataflow.worker"
```

and ran `terraform apply` again. This time I got the same error in the terraform output but there were no errors to be seen in the logs.

I then followed the advice given at https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/concepts/access-control#creating_jobs to also grant the roles/dataflow.admin:

```sh
gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding $PROJECT \
  --member="serviceAccount:dataflowdemo@${PROJECT}.iam.gserviceaccount.com" \
  --role="roles/dataflow.admin"
```

but there was no discernible difference from the previous attempt.

I then tried turning on [terraform debug logging](https://www.terraform.io/docs/internals/debugging.html)  which provided this info:

```
2020-12-31T16:04:13.129Z [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-google_v3.51.0_x5: ---[ REQUEST ]---------------------------------------
2020-12-31T16:04:13.129Z [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-google_v3.51.0_x5: POST /v1b3/projects/redacted/locations/europe-west1/templates?alt=json&prettyPrint=false HTTP/1.1
2020-12-31T16:04:13.129Z [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-google_v3.51.0_x5: Host: dataflow.googleapis.com
2020-12-31T16:04:13.129Z [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-google_v3.51.0_x5: User-Agent: google-api-go-client/0.5 Terraform/0.14.2 (+https://www.terraform.io) Terraform-Plugin-SDK/2.1.0 terraform-provider-google/dev
2020-12-31T16:04:13.129Z [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-google_v3.51.0_x5: Content-Length: 385
2020-12-31T16:04:13.129Z [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-google_v3.51.0_x5: Content-Type: application/json
2020-12-31T16:04:13.129Z [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-google_v3.51.0_x5: X-Goog-Api-Client: gl-go/1.14.5 gdcl/20201023
2020-12-31T16:04:13.129Z [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-google_v3.51.0_x5: Accept-Encoding: gzip
2020-12-31T16:04:13.129Z [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-google_v3.51.0_x5:
2020-12-31T16:04:13.129Z [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-google_v3.51.0_x5: {
2020-12-31T16:04:13.129Z [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-google_v3.51.0_x5:  "environment": {
2020-12-31T16:04:13.129Z [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-google_v3.51.0_x5:   "serviceAccountEmail": "serviceAccount:dataflowdemo@redacted.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
2020-12-31T16:04:13.129Z [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-google_v3.51.0_x5:   "tempLocation": "gs://jamiet-demo-functions/temp"
2020-12-31T16:04:13.129Z [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-google_v3.51.0_x5:  },
2020-12-31T16:04:13.129Z [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-google_v3.51.0_x5:  "gcsPath": "gs://dataflow-templates/latest/Word_Count",
2020-12-31T16:04:13.129Z [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-google_v3.51.0_x5:  "jobName": "wordcount",
2020-12-31T16:04:13.129Z [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-google_v3.51.0_x5:  "parameters": {
2020-12-31T16:04:13.129Z [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-google_v3.51.0_x5:   "inputFile": "gs://dataflow-samples/shakespeare/kinglear.txt",
2020-12-31T16:04:13.129Z [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-google_v3.51.0_x5:   "output": "gs://jamiet-demo-functions/wordcount/output"
2020-12-31T16:04:13.129Z [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-google_v3.51.0_x5:  }
2020-12-31T16:04:13.129Z [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-google_v3.51.0_x5: }
2020-12-31T16:04:13.129Z [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-google_v3.51.0_x5:
2020-12-31T16:04:13.129Z [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-google_v3.51.0_x5: -----------------------------------------------------
2020-12-31T16:04:14.647Z [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-google_v3.51.0_x5: 2020/12/31 16:04:14 [DEBUG] Google API Response Details:
2020-12-31T16:04:14.647Z [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-google_v3.51.0_x5: ---[ RESPONSE ]--------------------------------------
2020-12-31T16:04:14.647Z [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-google_v3.51.0_x5: HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
2020-12-31T16:04:14.647Z [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-google_v3.51.0_x5: Connection: close
2020-12-31T16:04:14.647Z [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-google_v3.51.0_x5: Transfer-Encoding: chunked
2020-12-31T16:04:14.647Z [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-google_v3.51.0_x5: Alt-Svc: h3-29=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-T051=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q050=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q046=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q043=":443"; ma=2592000,quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="46,43"
2020-12-31T16:04:14.647Z [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-google_v3.51.0_x5: Cache-Control: private
2020-12-31T16:04:14.647Z [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-google_v3.51.0_x5: Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
2020-12-31T16:04:14.647Z [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-google_v3.51.0_x5: Date: Thu, 31 Dec 2020 16:04:15 GMT
2020-12-31T16:04:14.647Z [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-google_v3.51.0_x5: Server: ESF
2020-12-31T16:04:14.647Z [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-google_v3.51.0_x5: Vary: Origin
2020-12-31T16:04:14.647Z [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-google_v3.51.0_x5: Vary: X-Origin
2020-12-31T16:04:14.647Z [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-google_v3.51.0_x5: Vary: Referer
2020-12-31T16:04:14.647Z [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-google_v3.51.0_x5: X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
2020-12-31T16:04:14.647Z [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-google_v3.51.0_x5: X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
2020-12-31T16:04:14.647Z [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-google_v3.51.0_x5: X-Xss-Protection: 0
2020-12-31T16:04:14.647Z [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-google_v3.51.0_x5:
2020-12-31T16:04:14.647Z [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-google_v3.51.0_x5: 1f9
2020-12-31T16:04:14.647Z [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-google_v3.51.0_x5: {
2020-12-31T16:04:14.647Z [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-google_v3.51.0_x5:   "error": {
2020-12-31T16:04:14.647Z [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-google_v3.51.0_x5:     "code": 400,
2020-12-31T16:04:14.647Z [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-google_v3.51.0_x5:     "message": "(dbacb1c39beb28c9): Current user cannot act as service account serviceAccount:dataflowdemo@redacted.iam.gserviceaccount.com.",
2020-12-31T16:04:14.647Z [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-google_v3.51.0_x5:     "errors": [
2020-12-31T16:04:14.647Z [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-google_v3.51.0_x5:       {
2020-12-31T16:04:14.647Z [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-google_v3.51.0_x5:         "message": "(dbacb1c39beb28c9): Current user cannot act as service account serviceAccount:dataflowdemo@redacted.iam.gserviceaccount.com.",
2020-12-31T16:04:14.647Z [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-google_v3.51.0_x5:         "domain": "global",
2020-12-31T16:04:14.647Z [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-google_v3.51.0_x5:         "reason": "badRequest"
2020-12-31T16:04:14.647Z [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-google_v3.51.0_x5:       }
2020-12-31T16:04:14.647Z [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-google_v3.51.0_x5:     ],
2020-12-31T16:04:14.647Z [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-google_v3.51.0_x5:     "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
orm-provider-google_v3.51.0_x5:   }
2020-12-31T16:04:14.647Z [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-google_v3.51.0_x5: }
2020-12-31T16:04:14.647Z [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-google_v3.51.0_x5:
2020-12-31T16:04:14.647Z [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-google_v3.51.0_x5: 0
2020-12-31T16:04:14.647Z [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-google_v3.51.0_x5:
2020-12-31T16:04:14.647Z [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-google_v3.51.0_x5:
2020-12-31T16:04:14.647Z [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-google_v3.51.0_x5: -----------------------------------------------------
```

The error being returned from dataflow.googleapis.com is clearly evident:

> Current user cannot act as service account serviceAccount:dataflowdemo@redacted.iam.gserviceaccount.com

At this stage I am puzzled as to why I can see an error being returned from the Google's dataflow API but there is nothing in the GCP logs indicating that an error occurred.

Then tho I had a bit of a lightbulb moment. Why does that error message mention "service account serviceAccount"? Then it hit me, I'd defined the service account incorrectly. Terraform code should have been:

```
resource "google_dataflow_job" "wordcount" {
  # https://stackoverflow.com/a/59931467/201657
  name              = "wordcount"
  template_gcs_path = "gs://dataflow-templates/latest/Word_Count"
  temp_gcs_location = "gs://${local.name-prefix}-functions/temp"
  parameters = {
    inputFile = "gs://dataflow-samples/shakespeare/kinglear.txt"
    output = "gs://${local.name-prefix}-functions/wordcount/output"
  }
  service_account_email = data.google_service_account.sa.email
}
```

I corrected it and it worked straight away. User error!!!

I then set about removing the various permissions that I'd added:

```sh
gcloud projects remove-iam-policy-binding $PROJECT \
  --member="serviceAccount:dataflowdemo@${PROJECT}.iam.gserviceaccount.com" \
  --role="roles/dataflow.admin"
gcloud projects remove-iam-policy-binding $PROJECT \
  --member="serviceAccount:dataflowdemo@${PROJECT}.iam.gserviceaccount.com" \
  --role="roles/dataflow.worker"
```

and `terraform apply` still worked. However, after removing the grant of role `roles/dataflow.worker` the job failed with error:

> Workflow failed. Causes: Permissions verification for controller service account failed. IAM role roles/dataflow.worker should be granted to controller service account dataflowdemo@redacted.iam.gserviceaccount.com.

so clearly the documentation regarding the appropriate roles to grant (https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/concepts/access-control#creating_jobs) is spot on.

As may be apparent, I started writing this post before I knew what the problem was and I thought it might be useful to document my investigation somewhere. Now that I've finished the investigation and the problem turns out to be one of [PEBCAK](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/PEBCAK) its probably not so relevant to this thread anymore, and certainly shouldn't be accepted as an answer. Nevertheless, there is probably some useful information in here about how to go about investigating issues with terraform calling Google APIs, and it also reiterates the required role grants, so I'll leave it here in case it ever turns out to be useful.

Answer (score 4):

I just hit this problem again so posting my solution up here as I fully expect I'll get bitten by this again at some point.

I was getting error:

> Error: googleapi: Error 403: (a00eba23d59c1fa3): Current user cannot act as service account dataflow-controller-sa@myproject.iam.gserviceaccount.com. Causes: (a00eba23d59c15ac): Current user cannot act as service account dataflow-controller-sa@myproject.iam.gserviceaccount.com., forbidden

I was deploying the dataflow job, via terraform, using a different service account, `deployer@myproject.iam.gserviceaccount.com`

The solution was to grant that service account the `roles/iam.serviceAccountUser` role:

```
gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding myproject \
    --member=serviceAccount:deployer@myproject.iam.gserviceaccount.com \
    --role=roles/iam.serviceAccountUser
```

For those that prefer custom IAM roles over predefined IAM roles the specific permission that was missing was `iam.serviceAccounts.actAs`.

Answer (score 1):

**Issue Got Resolved!**

Go to GCP -> Console -> IAM -> ServiceAccount Email -> Add Permission -> Service Account User. as below

[image]