# Deploy a Dataflow with Terraform

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, google-cloud-dataflow, terraform-provider-gcp

I'm trying to deploy a Dataflow template with Terraform in GCloud.

There are several tutorial which include some terraform code. There are 2 options:Use *module* like the following [link](https://github.com/terraform-google-modules/terraform-google-dataflow/blob/master/examples/dlp_api_example/main.tf) or  use *resource* like the following [link](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/google/r/dataflow_job.html)

With both options I have the following error:

```
Error: googleapi: got HTTP response code 502 with body: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang=en>
  <meta charset=utf-8>
  <meta name=viewport content="initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">
  <title>Error 502 (Server Error)!!1</title>
  <style>
    *{margin:0;padding:0}html,code{font:15px/22px arial,sans-serif}html{background:#fff;color:#222;padding:15px}body{margin:7% auto 0;max-width:390px;min-height:180px;padding:30px 0 15px}* > body{background:url(//www.google.com/images/errors/robot.png) 100% 5px no-repeat;padding-right:205px}p{margin:11px 0 22px;overflow:hidden}ins{color:#777;text-decoration:none}a img{border:0}@media screen and (max-width:772px){body{background:none;margin-top:0;max-width:none;padding-right:0}}#logo{background:url(//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png) no-repeat;margin-left:-5px}@media only screen and (min-resolution:192dpi){#logo{background:url(//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png) no-repeat 0% 0%/100% 100%;-moz-border-image:url(//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png) 0}}@media only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:2){#logo{background:url(//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png) no-repeat;-webkit-background-size:100% 100%}}#logo{display:inline-block;height:54px;width:150px}
  </style>
  <a href=//www.google.com/><span id=logo aria-label=Google></span></a>
  <p><b>502.</b> <ins>That’s an error.</ins>
  <p>The server encountered a temporary error and could not complete your request.<p>Please try again in 30 seconds.  <ins>That’s all we know.</ins>


  on .terraform\modules\dataflow-job\terraform-google-modules-terraform-google-dataflow-722fc1d\main.tf line 17, in resource "google_dataflow_job" "dataflow_job":
  17: resource "google_dataflow_job" "dataflow_job" {
```

I have tried running from my local computer and also from the cloud shell inside GCP.

The problem should be in the dataflow module, because I also tried to create other resource like a bucket and compute engine and it works without any problem.

The dataflow template is storaged in a bucket before I run the terraform script.

Terraform version: 0.12.19

The code:

**main.tf**

```
variable "project_id" {}
<...>


provider "google" {
  version = "~> 2.8.0"
  region  = var.region
}

resource "google_dataflow_job" "dataflow_job" {
  project               = var.project_id
  region                = var.region
  zone                  = "${var.region}-a"
  name                  = var.project_name
  on_delete             = "cancel"
  max_workers           = var.max_workers
  template_gcs_path     = var.template_location
  temp_gcs_location     = "gs://${var.gcs_location}/tmp_dir"
  service_account_email = var.controller_service_account_email
  parameters = {
    inputPubSub       = var.input_PubSub_subscription
    outputPubSub      = var.output_PubSub_subscription
  }
  machine_type     = var.machine_type
}
```

**terraform.tfvars**

```
<...>
template_location = "gs://www/zzz/template"
gcs_location= "gs://www/yyy"
<...>
```

**To test if my code is wrong, I also tried directly from the code of [link](https://github.com/terraform-google-modules/terraform-google-dataflow/blob/master/examples/dlp_api_example/main.tf) and also the same error.**

Am I missing any dependence to add to the code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that you have declared `temp_gcs_location` as `"gs://${var.gcs_location}/tmp_dir"` but then, in `terraform.tvars` you set `gcs_location` as `"gs://www/yyy"` (so the `gs://` prefix appears twice). In any case, the job should be launched but then fail to create.

I made a minimal example with the following versions:

```sh
$ terraform --version
Terraform v0.12.20
+ provider.google v3.5.0
```

and using the Google-provided [word count](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/templates/provided-templates?hl=en#wordcount) template. My `main.tf` file is:

```yaml
variable "project_id" {
  type        = string
  description = "GCP Project ID."
}
variable "gcs_location" {
  type        = string
  description = "GCS bucket name (no gs:// prefix)."
}

provider "google" {
  project = var.project_id
  region  = "us-central1"
  zone    = "us-central1-c"
}

resource "google_dataflow_job" "wordcount" {
  name              = "wordcount"
  template_gcs_path = "gs://dataflow-templates/latest/Word_Count"
  temp_gcs_location = "gs://${var.gcs_location}/temp"
  parameters = {
    inputFile = "gs://dataflow-samples/shakespeare/kinglear.txt"
    output = "gs://${var.gcs_location}/wordcount/output"
  }
}
```

and `df.tfvars` (change with the appropriate values):

```yaml
project_id = "PROJECT_ID"
gcs_location = "BUCKET_NAME"
```

I run it with:

```sh
terraform apply -var-file="df.tvars"
```

and the job is successfully created:

```sh
google_dataflow_job.wordcount: Creating...
google_dataflow_job.wordcount: Creation complete after 3s [id=2020-01-27_...]
```

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Thank you Guillem. I will try what you did. What you mentioned about the `temp_gcs_location` it was an error due copy/paste of the last example, because in my previous examples I did correctly but also with the fail result. Could be due to the service account? Did you run from your computer?

Comment: To verify if this is due to the service account, you could add the role Dataflow Admin[1], to this service account; this role is the minimum required to create and manage Dataflow jobs.

  [1]: https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/concepts/access-control#roles

Comment: @IoTuser yes, I figured it was a typo or something. I ran it from a GCE instance with all GCP scopes enabled and Default Compute Engine Service Account

Comment: I think my problem was due the region and zone, your script worked for me, so finally, after debugging mine, I can deploy it with: region= `europe-west1` and zone= `europe-west1-c`

Comment: I don't see `terraform import` section in the `terraform` documentation for `dataflow` . So , can't we import the state of existing dataflow jobs using `terraform` . I am referring to https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/google/r/dataflow_job.html